# Sliding tab добавление нажатия android?

Tags: android, sliding

Я внедрил у себя в приложении sliding tabs, используя видеоролик, но после запуска на эмуляторе я заметил что перейти на другую вкладку мы можем только жестом смахивания, а вот перейти нажав на другую вкладку я не могу, может я что-то не учел когда добавлял этот вид вкладок, или в этой разновидности вкладок нету возможности перехода на другую вкладку нажав на нее? Для работы с Sliding Tabs я использовал такой туториал: [ссылка](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcnT-3F-9JA). Буду очень благодарен за ценные советы.

Comment: clickable=true ставили в xml? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959298/android-material-design-click-event-on-tabs

Comment: нет, сейчас попробую поставить.